# Telegram bot can't delete message

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I have received the following error while trying to delete a `Message`:

```
2018-04-10 13:58:57,646 (__init__.py:292 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 400 Bad Request. Response body:
[b'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message can\'t be deleted"}']"
```

Why message can't be deleted?

```
import config
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello World')
  bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id)


if __name__ == '__main__':
 bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please translate your post to English, as Stack Overflow is English-only.

Comment: How can I check if I have the right to delete it? The bot is not in any group. Removes its message, as I understand it, the documentation says that it can delete its own messages.

Answer (score 5):

Check your `Message`. There are following [limitations](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#deletemessage) on deleting messages by bots:

> - A message can only be deleted if it was sent less than 48 hours ago.
> - Bots can delete outgoing messages in groups and supergroups.
> - Bots granted can_post_messages permissions can delete outgoing messages in channels.
> - If the bot is an administrator of a group, it can delete any message there.
> - If the bot has can_delete_messages permission in a supergroup or a channel, it can delete any message there.
>     Returns True on success.

Comment: The bot is not in any group. Removes its message, as I understand it, the documentation says that it can delete its own messages.

Comment: I understood. A bot only in a group can delete messages. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The handler you've placed to operate your bot only processes messages that the **user has sent, not the bot**.

the `message` object inside the `repeat_all_messages()` function is the message that the **user** has sent, and in this case you are only echoing it. I would try to do the following:

Since you know that next message is sent by you, you can increment the `message_id` by 1, since your message's id is +1 away from the one the user has sent, i.e:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello World')
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to answer this.

Here's a demo which shows bot sending "Hi" message to the user every 10 seconds and deleting previous sent message

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['hi'])
def hi(message):
  x = -1 
  while(True):
    if(x != -1): # not to delete first time
      bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, x.message_id)
    x = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hi")
    time.sleep(10) #wait for 10 seconds

bot.polling()
```

`bot.send_message()` returns the Message object. We will store the object in a variable x and delete it by using `x.message_id`.